# Getting error as Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum

Tags: tensorflow

Can anyone help me with this, tried everything but it always throws the same error

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
W0413 19:15:32.762504  4348 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
W0413 19:15:32.762504  4348 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
W0413 19:15:32.762504  4348 util.py:194] Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.momentum
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: These messages simply warn you that the parameters `iter`, `decay` and `momentum` of the `optimizer` could not be restored from the checkpoint (because you changed the optimizer apparently). Thanks!